# Creating kiosk app with web browser extension

Tags: python, web, browser, uwp, kiosk

I would like to create a kiosk application that wraps a web browser and enables extensions.
This application needs to be launched at startup of windows 10 pro. It has to display a web page and an extension that hide html elements like buttons and links.

I have tried to develop a little application with python and selenium. It actually works but the application start too slow and shows the desktop. I tried some startup application mechanism on Windows but none of them can launch the application fast enough to hide the desktop.

Now I am following the uwp way. It solves all the problems about the kiosk implementation but with WebView2 I think I cant use extensions. I was thinking about injecting javascript code on the fly but I dont now how to do it or if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WebView2`'s [ExecuteScriptAsync(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/javascript) method to run JavaScript.